# iOS7 - receipts not validating at sandbox - error 21002 (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: php, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios7, sandbox

I'm converting an app from iOS6 to iOS7. Before I used the deprecated `transactionReceipt` method so now I'm trying the recommended methods to retrieve the receipt, and  then encode in base 64:

```
NSData *working = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
// Tried 64 or 76 chars/line and LF or CR line endings
NSString *receipt = [working base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
```

The above is the only change in the code. Below is how I validate it, no changes:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue,
     ^{
         NSMutableString *url = [NSMutableString string];

         [url appendFormat:@"%@", WEB_SERVICE];
         [url appendFormat:@"receipt=%@", receipt];

         NSStringEncoding encoding;
         NSError *error = [NSError new];
         NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
         NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

         // check json and error
         // ... code omitted
    }
```

On the server side, this is the PHP code I use to verify the receipt, no change other than trying the sandbox for any error:

```
// Encode as JSON
$json = json_encode(array('receipt-data' => $receipt));
// Try production first, if it doesn't work, then try the sandbox
$working = postJSONToURL('https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt', $json, false);
error_log('production - '.print_r($working, true));
if (@$working['status'] !== 0) // === 21007)
    $working = postJSONToURL('https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt', $json, true);
error_log('sandbox - '.print_r($working, true));
```

This is the error log output:

```
production - Array\n(\n    [status] => 21002\n    [exception] => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException\n)\n
sandbox - Array\n(\n    [status] => 21002\n    [exception] => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException\n)\n
```

It looks like I'm throwing all kinds of exceptions over at Apple!

Again the only difference is how the receipt is retrieved and encoded. Has anyone encountered this problem and fixed it?

Thanks for reading.

/YR

As requested, code for PostJSONToURL:

```
function postJSONToURL($url, $json, $disableSSLVerify = false)
{
    $resource = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: '.strlen($json)));
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    if ($disableSSLVerify)
    {
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    }
    //curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    //curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp = fopen('/tmp/curl_output'.rand(1000, 9999).'.txt', 'w'));
    $contents = json_decode(curl_exec($resource), true);
    if (!$contents)
        $contents = array();
    curl_close($resource);
    //fclose($fp);
    return $contents;
}
```

New details after some experimenting, have determined that sending the existing data as base 64 encoded is likely encroaching on some internal limit. If it exceeds some internal limit, the data isn't even sent, it fails locally on the device, below that, it is sent. Columns are: data format, size of encoded data, whether it reached the server:

```
raw receipt data         5K  N/A
base64 no options     6.66K  yes
base64 76 chars/line  6.75K  no
base64 64 chars/line  6.77K  no
hex coded               10K  no
```

Note that the difference between successfully sending and not sending is less than 100 bytes.

Comment: I must admit I'm not familiar with this area but is this Java? As opposed to javascript?

Comment: This is **not** connected to **JAVA** but _JavaScript_. The common thing between the two is that `"Java".equals("JavaScript".substring(0,4))` (and _this_ was Java) Be more careful next time.

Comment: @ppeterka66 My personal favourite for this is java is to javascript as car is to carpet

Comment: @RichardTingle Oooooh...  I'll remember this one :) Made my day for sure...

Comment: This is not javascript. Note the error message in the subject line and the logged errors at the bottom. The servers at Apple are using java. Please read the posts before making changes like these.

Comment: JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation, now I'm really confused

Comment: JSON is a common standard for passing information via web services, the original acronym meaning the notation can be processed as-is by JavaScript, but it is implemented on many platforms because it is very light weight, as compared to SOAP and others. So this posting has Objective-C, PHP (on one server), Java (on another server), and JSON as method of passing information.

Comment: @Enzino - Yes, confirmed that what was received is the same as what was sent.

Comment: @Enzino - I doubt it, no changes made to that function, but included for your review.

Comment: @Enzino - No, legal device.

Comment: What you have in $receipt ? inside json_encoded $json i mean ?

Comment: how about this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927258/in-app-purchase-receipt-verification-within-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927258/in-app-purchase-receipt-verification-within-app)

Comment: @Sung-PilLim - note this is about server side validation, not on the local device

Comment: @Omiga - whatever Apple provides, approximately 5 Kb of opaque, probably encrypted data, if it is sent (see additional details in question) have confirmed that the length and checksum at the server side are unchanged

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had this problem and looked everywhere, including on Apple's development forums. Apple will give a couple of stock replies, and that's it. I think it's a bug on Apple's side. Validation locally on the device will work, so try to convert to that. If you absolutely must use server side validation, only `transactionReceipt` seems to work right now.

The function is just deprecated, not banned, so I would just use it and hope Apple approves of the app. In fact, it's what I just did, fingers crossed, waiting for approval.

You can turn off the warning in Xcode by bracketing your code like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
// code using transactionReceipt
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Was your app approved?

Comment: Yes, CWC - CrossWord Creator v1.1

Comment: I am currently having success in server-side receipt verification with iOS7 style receipts. See below.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869828/base64-encoding-weirdness-for-ios7-in-app-purchase-receipt-server-verification?lq=1

Answer (score 7):

I am having success with iOS7 receipts, obtained from the app bundle using:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] performSelector:@selector(appStoreReceiptURL)];
receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

The response, to my server, from Apple's server to the iOS7 style receipt differs greatly from that to the previous receipt style. Here's an example validated receipt:

```
{"status":0,
    "environment":"Sandbox",
    "receipt":
    {"receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox",
        "adam_id":0,
        "bundle_id":"<snip>",
        "application_version":"1.0",
        "download_id":0,
        "request_date":"2013-11-12 01:43:06 Etc\/GMT",
        "request_date_ms":"1384220586352",
        "request_date_pst":"2013-11-11 17:43:06 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "in_app":[
                  {"quantity":"1",
                      "product_id":"<snip>",
                      "transaction_id":"1000000092978110",
                      "original_transaction_id":"1000000092978110",
                      "purchase_date":"2013-11-12 01:36:49 Etc\/GMT",
                      "purchase_date_ms":"1384220209000",
                      "purchase_date_pst":"2013-11-11 17:36:49 America\/Los_Angeles",
                      "original_purchase_date":"2013-11-12 01:36:49 Etc\/GMT",
                      "original_purchase_date_ms":"1384220209000",
                      "original_purchase_date_pst":"2013-11-11 17:36:49 America\/Los_Angeles",
                      "is_trial_period":"false"}
                  ]
    }
}
```

The pretty-printed indentation was for my benefit, not strictly speaking as given by Apple.

Here is the guts of my client side:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:[credentials dictionary]];

// receipt is an object of my own making, but base64String just returns an
// NSString representation of the receipt data.
parameters[PURCHASE_RECEIPT] = [receipt base64String];

NSURLRequest *request =
    [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]
        requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                URLString:urlString
                parameters:parameters];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
        initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

<snip>

[operation start];
```

And here is the guts of what I'm using on the server side where the URL is either the production or sandbox verification server:

```
// Some code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php
private static function validateReceipt($receiptData, $URL) {
    // Connect to Apple server and validate.
    $data = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $receiptData));

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    // This: 'content' => http_build_query($data),
    // seems to generate an error (21002)
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($URL, false, $context);

    //Utils::writeToLog("done validateReceipt: " . $result);

    // See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
    // for the use of === comparison.
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        // Decode the result as an associative array.
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
}
```

I'm having success with this code with both iOS6 and iOS7 style receipts.

Comment: This is working for me too, iOS 7.1.1. You can test this by saving the JSON string into a file receipt.txt, then using the command "curl -d @receipt.txt https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt".

Comment: I run this file for sandbox testing, and got response code 21002, just now. Is that mean Apple already revoke this?

Comment: This worked for me in addition to the above answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869828/base64-encoding-weirdness-for-ios7-in-app-purchase-receipt-server-verification?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms: error 21002 (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) while validating io7 style receipts from my own server.

It turned out there were two problems:

1. My receipt data was bad.  Somehow while passing the data to my server it ended up with a bunch of "\r\n" characters in the base64 encoded receipt data.  (I stripped these out with some search and replace code).
2. If you are using auto-renewing subscriptions then you must pass in two parameters in the JSON payload to verifyReceipt: "receipt-data" but also "password" which should be your shared secret from itunes connect.

Once I fixed those two things my verifyReceipt http requests worked as expected.

Comment: how did u removed "\r\n" i guess i have same problem

Comment: How you remove "\r\n" would depend on the programming language.   I was parsing the receipt on the server side using Java, but whatever language you use you can do some sort of string manipulation where you replace "\r\n" with "" (empty string).  In Objective C you could use the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method of NSString.

Comment: Could you post a valid example receipt? :)

Comment: This helped me storing the receipt data in my mysql database and fetching it via PHP and not getting 21002 anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) uses the url and filename safe base64 from [RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc4648/?include_text=1) which has -_ as the last two characters. +/ is typical of many implementations.

OP's code only works on 10.9+ or 7.0+, here is a previously private API that allows support for 4.0+ and 10.6+:

```
[NSData base64Encoding]
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer since OP was using Apple's base64 encoding, but it helped me!